# Create HTML table with hyperlink from JSON Object

Tags: javascript

I have an application which returns a JSONObject. I am able to get data from JSON object using below code.

---

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0  Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
    <head>
    <style type="text/css">


table, td, th
{
border:1px collapse black;
font-family:Arial;
font-size :small;
}
th
{
background-color:green;
color:white;
}
.hideMe
{
    /*display : none;*/
    /*visibility: hidden;*/
}

</style>
   <script type="text/javascript" language="jscript" src="http://jqueryjs.googlecode.com/files/jquery-1.3.2.min.js">   
   </script>
   <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
           var host = "somehost";
           var mystr = "http://"+ host  +"/rest/bpm/wle/v1/exposed/process";   // use get for this
           var ulink = "";

           $(document).ready(function () {
           $.get(mystr, function (data) {
                   var obj = JSON.parse(data);
               var thtml = "<table id='proctable'>";

                   for (i = 0; i < obj.data.exposedItemsList.length; i++) {
                       ulink = "http://" + host + obj.data.exposedItemsList[i].startURL;
                       thtml = thtml + "<tr><td><a onclick='my_function()' href='javascript:void(0)'>" + obj.data.exposedItemsList[i].display + "</a></td><td id='linkcell' class='hideMe'>" + ulink + "</td></tr>";                   
               }
               thtml = thtml + "</table>";
               document.getElementById('contentdiv').innerHTML = thtml;
           });
       });

       //javascript 
       my_function = null;

       //jquery
       $(function () {
           function generateBPDInstance() {
               $.post(ulink, function (taskdata) {
                   var tobj = JSON.parse(taskdata);
                   alert(tobj.data.tasks[0].name);
                   alert(tobj.data.tasks[0].tkiid);                  
               });
           }
           my_function = generateBPDInstance;
           ulink = "";
       })
`

   </script>
</head>
<body>
 <form name="myform">           
            <div id="contentdiv">
            <table id="proctable">
            </table>
            </div>
        </form>
</body>
</html>
```

---

The above html creates a table showing a list of the returned values. I also want to get rowIndex of hyperlink and pass value of column2 to function generateBPDInstance.

I am not so good at HTML and Jquery. Please suggest how can I get rowIndex for HTML table which is created through javascript.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The simple way is :

change your table building to this

for (i = 0; i < obj.data.exposedItemsList.length; i++) {
                       ulink = "http://" + host + obj.data.exposedItemsList[i].startURL;
                       thtml = thtml + "" + obj.data.exposedItemsList[i].display + "" + ulink + "";

function my_function(e){
//e is the row index and when you call document.getLementById("proctable").rows[e]; this will give you the complete row.

}

--this is a simple way, and if you want traverse the tree and get , you always have parentnode or you can use jquery $(object).parent() to get the parent of hyperlink and traverse.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.Above code just generate plain html table. Where do I provide hyperlink and call the function with rowIndex?

Answer (score 0):

You problem is "pass value of column2 to function generateBPDInstance". Why not pass it already while generating the table?

```
for (i = 0; i < obj.data.exposedItemsList.length; i++) {
   ulink = "http://" + host + obj.data.exposedItemsList[i].startURL;
   thtml = thtml + "<tr><td><a onclick='my_function('" + ulink + "')' href='javascript:void(0)'>" + obj.data.exposedItemsList[i].display + "</a></td><td id='linkcell' class='hideMe'>" + ulink + "</td></tr>";
 // ------------------------------------------------------^ pass the value
}
```

Add parameter to your function `generateBPDInstance`

```
function generateBPDInstance(ulink) {
   //--------------------------^----
   $.post(ulink, function (taskdata) {
      var tobj = JSON.parse(taskdata);
      alert(tobj.data.tasks[0].name);
      alert(tobj.data.tasks[0].tkiid);                  
   });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. I have already tried this, but It throws javascript error.Webpage error details:

User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; InfoPath.3; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E)
Timestamp: Mon, 3 Sep 2012 04:03:33 UTC


Message: Expected ')'
Line: 1
Char: 17
Code: 0
URI: file:///C:/Users/996458/Desktop/HTMLPage.htm


Message: Expected ')'
Line: 1
Char: 17
Code: 0
URI: file:///C:/Users/996458/Desktop/HTMLPage.htm

Comment: Probably the quotes around `ulink`. Updated it.